# I want to check back my process which i ran like ' "Command do something" &' but in background

Tags: command-line

basically ran a webserver but i want to check the IP and port number. So how should I view it back?

Answer (score 3):

When you run a job in the background, you get an answer like below:

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 112488
```

The [1] is the job number. So running:

```
$ fg 1
sleep 100
```

will pull job 1 to the foreground.

If you run a job without `&` you can suspend it with `CTRL-z` and put it in the background with `bg <jobnumber>`:

```
$ sleep 100
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 100
$ bg 1
[1]+ sleep 100 &
$
```